# Properly extract SOAB body ignoring the SOAP general stuff in .Net 6

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, soap, .net-6.0

I have XML like this

```
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ValidationResponse>
            <Context>
                <MainInformation>
                    <ServiceID>10</ServiceID>
                    <TransactionDate>2015-07-29T09:06:05.694+02:00</TransactionDate>
                </MainInformation>
            </Context>
            <PlayerStatus>
                <PlayerCPRStatus>CPRIsRegistered</PlayerCPRStatus>
                <PlayerAge>AgeIs18OrAbove</PlayerAge>
                <ExclusionStatus>PersonIsNotRegistered</ExclusionStatus>
            </PlayerStatus>
        </ValidationResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I wanna ignore envelope and Body elements and desereliaze this XML into C# object.But could not do it  always getting envelope was not expected innerexception.

This is the code that i try to run

```
public class Resposnse
    {
        [XmlElement("Age")]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PlayerStatus")]
        public string CPRStatus { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ExclusionStatus")]
        public string ExclusionStatus { get; set; }
    }


string xml = "mentioned xml in example";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resposnse));

Resposnse xmlResponse;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    xmlResponse = (Resposnse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

The result is

**InvalidOperationException: envelope was not expected**

Any help ?

Comment: If you want to deserialize into a class this way, the class must have the same structure as the XML. Incidentally your XmlElement declarations don't match the XML either.

Comment: Can you pleaase show in code how propelry fix this so far i have been workling only with JSOn so this is y first time dealing with xml

Answer (score 1):

Use ReadToFolling to move to desired element

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            xReader.ReadToFollowing("PlayerStatus");
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resposnse));
            Resposnse response = (Resposnse)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
            
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PlayerStatus")]
    public class Resposnse
    {
        [XmlElement("PlayerAge")]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PlayerCPRStatus")]
        public string CPRStatus { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ExclusionStatus")]
        public string ExclusionStatus { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

the shortest way

```
Resposnse playerStatus = XElement.Parse(xml)
.Descendants("PlayerStatus")
.Select(xe => new Resposnse
{
    Age = xe.Element("PlayerAge").Value,
    CPRStatus = xe.Element("PlayerCPRStatus").Value,
    ExclusionStatus = xe.Element("ExclusionStatus").Value
}
).FirstOrDefault();
```

and you don't need any xml attributes in this case

```
public class Resposnse
{
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string CPRStatus { get; set; }
    public string ExclusionStatus { get; set; }
}
```